# generate select options inside of generated table rows

Tags: jquery

I am using a method that creates table rows based on the number of lines in my dataset. The current function creates the rows correctly, But I am trying to create an array of all the integers up to lines[i].qty_printed, and add that array as options to my  for each row created.
Any advice on how to do this?

```
var myDataHtml = response.my.map(function(data) {
var lines = my.list_set;

for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
   var quantities = lines[i].qty_printed'
      linesHtml += '<tr>' +
                      '<td><select id="testlist"' + lines[i].qty_printed + '></select> </td>' +
                   '</tr>';

}
return linesHtml;

});

$'#myTableBody').html(myDataHtml);
```

Comment: You have a few characters that are missing or out of place. The first one is a ```'``` right after ```lines[i].qty_printed``` on the third line. The second one is a missing ```(``` in the last line (```$'#myTableBody').html(...);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I correctly understand the problem, but you could add an `option` for it in a loop as below

```
var qty = lines[i].qty_printed;
linesHtml += '<tr>' +
                '<td><select id="testlist' + qty + '">';
if (Number.isInteger( qty )) {
  for (var q=1; q <= qty; q++) 
    linesHtml += '<option val="'+ q +'">Printed ' + q + '</option>';
  }
}

linesHtml +=    '</select> </td>' +
             '</tr>';
```

Comment: Basically the table is several generated <select> boxes. if lines[i].qty_printed is an integer, i am trying to add an array from 1 up to qty_printed for the <option>'s.

Comment: Yes this works the way I wanted it to. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad I could help